# ubuntu 18.04 LTS not recognizing intel wifi card 8260 on dell latitude E7470 laptop

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi, wifi-hardware-switch

My wifi was working up until today, when I could not turn on wifi and in the wifi settings window it says "wifi adapter not found".

I've been looking at all answers to do with keywords "ubuntu wifi intel 18" but I haven't found any fixes.

output of `lspci -nn | grep -i network`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:093c] (rev 3a)
```

output of `rfkill list all`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5832 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b91 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of `ifconfig -a`

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.2.80.156  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.2.80.255
        inet6 fe80::8ef0:5a10:43a2:23b8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:f1:0e:1d:18:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20411  bytes 12494793 (12.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8973  bytes 1376328 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xe1300000-e1320000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1782  bytes 193176 (193.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1782  bytes 193176 (193.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:08:cf:37:96:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: "Hard blocked: yes" suggests that the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. Please find it and switch it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @amy-huang as per this Dell Latitude E7470 Keyboard Guide: `https://www.dell.com/support/article/in/en/inbsd1/sln306885/dell-latitude-e7470-keyboard-guide?lang=en`,  `Fn + PrtScr Toggle Wireless (Wi-Fi) On/Off`. Press both `Fn` and `PrtScr` at once and see if it turns WiFi on.

Comment: I think that key combo worked? I’m not sure though, because pressing again/rebooting does not toggle the wifi off again and I didn’t check when reopening my laptop if the wifi was already re-enabled. Thanks anyways ahahaha

Comment: Excellent example of providing the information we need to help you! Done good!